# How can I disable the End key for all operating systems(Windows and Linux)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, keyboard, grub

I noticed an issue in my Laptop recently, everytime I opened a webpage it would auto scroll to the bottom of the page. Initially I thought the PageDown key might be stuck, and so I googled for similar errors, finally I used Passmark Keyboard Test and it turned out the End Key was getting randomly pressed, so I guess it is stuck and I cant get it "unstuck". So I used Sharpkeys and turned off the End key and now Windows 10 has no issues. 
My main issue is that I use both Ubuntu(64bit) and Windows 10, and this issue still persists on Ubuntu and also Grub menu when the system boots up. I think this is because the Sharpkeys fix uses registry. Is there any way to deactivate the End key for all the operating systems or like a hardware disable such that it doesnt get clicked even for the Grub boot menu?
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: The permanent fix would be to replace the faulty keyboard all together. If you're on laptop, then you could unplug the keyboard from its socket and just use external keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a mechanical problem with your keyboard. I'd try cleaning or even [replacing the keyboard](http://www.pcworld.com/article/259112/how_to_replace_your_laptop_keyboard.html).

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is, just wanted to find a temporary fix by disabling the key, I did it for windows but wanted to know if I can universally disable a key in the System. Is it possible to get a keyboard replaced at a Lenovo Service Center? I really dont trust in replacing it myself.

Comment: Laptop keyboard replacements are straightforward. Any computer shop will do it for you, but you might have to wait until they get the right keyboard in stock.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to deactivate the End key for all the operating systems or like a hardware disable such that it doesnt get clicked even for the Grub boot menu?

No.  This is not a standard feature of the BIOS.  Software like Grub tends to be rather focused on the minimal tasks that the software performs.  In truth, the developers of such software tend to do a rather impressive job of cramming such functionality into a rather small number of bytes.  Playing around with an option like "disable one key" is probably not widely supported by boot loaders, although maybe (and this is a big "maybe") such functionality might be supported by some larger boot loaders (like grub) as part of internationalization efforts.  So, if the software supports different keyboard layouts, maybe another layout might treat the keyboard scan code of the "End" key as something different (which might get ignored).  However, you might also end up breaking some other keys (perhaps especially the arrow keys, and maybe even something important like the Enter key).

Even if you could break the End key in grub, each operating system probably assumes that it has the job of starting to support hardware, including keyboard support.  That is the common behavior.  Operating systems may assume that earlier code, such as the BIOS and boot loader, provided only very minimal support of the hardware, and that the operating system (including any drivers that get used) may typically provide support that is equal or superior to the simplistic software used during the earlier parts of the system boot process.  Therefore, to provide the best experience for end users, operating systems are typically designed to not handle this task without relying too much on the configuration details provided by earlier parts of the system.

The end result is that you will likely need to find a solution for every single operating system that you use.  (The good news is that if you can solve this for the operating system, most software will trust the operating system, so once you have this set in an operating system, you won't need to go around re-configuring most pieces of software.)

Note: My information is based on some dated technologies, like BIOS.  (U)EFI might provide some functionality that I haven't read up on, so if the world does offer a glimmer of hope that my answer is wrong, then I think (U)EFI may be the glimmer you may want to further research.  Even if (U)EFI does have some functionality, different operating systems might provide different amounts of support for such a setting.  So if you spend your time researching information for the operating systems you desire to use, you might be better off anyway.  If (U)EFI doesn't provide you a solution, I suspect the widely-used standards may not typically provide you wish any other solution.

Comment: Thanks alot for the information, I'll check if I can get the keyboard repaired or something. Can you suggest some links which explain how to disable a key in Ubuntu? I can manage the Grub menu even with the problem by keeping the arrow key pressed and changing, and I have a temporary fix for Windows.

Comment: (I'm not planning to answer your question for Ubuntu anytime soon.  If you don't get more feedback, consider making a separate Ubuntu-specific question here on SuperUser or, even better, on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), which is another Stack Exchange site.)